# Why does python bayesian optimization give wrong answers

Tags: python, bayesian, nonlinear-optimization

I am using [the Python package `dragonfly`](https://github.com/dragonfly/dragonfly) to perform some Bayesian optimization. I am testing out on a simple example (minimize y=x within [-10, 10], the answer is clearly -10). However, I get different results depending on how I implement "minimise" function:

```python
import numpy as np
from dragonfly import load_config, minimise_function

def fopt(x):
  tx = np.array([x[0][0]])
  return tx + 0.01*(np.random.random() - 1)

domain_vars = [{'type': 'float',  'min': -10.0, 'max': 10.0, 'dim': 1}]
config_params = {'domain': domain_vars}
newconfig = load_config(config_params)
max_num_evals = 100
opt_val, opt_pt, history = minimise_function(fopt, newconfig.domain, max_num_evals,
                                               config=newconfig)
print(opt_val, opt_pt)
```

The printed output is: `-10.00976228312294 [array([1.59872116e-14])]`, which is clearly finding the minimum value, but not the minimum point (should be -10).

However, if I use a different method:

```python
min_val, min_pt, history = minimise_function(lambda x: x + 0.01*(np.random.random() - 1), [[-10, 10]], 100)
print(min_val, min_pt)
```

I get the correct answer: `-10.009947789035548 [-10.]`

Why is this the case?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? The first implementation does some non-obvious slicing and casting - perhaps you could motivate that a bit better.

Comment: Does this library support optimizing non-deterministic functions? It's not totally clear from the documentation.

Comment: The library does support this. The example I posted is one example, but I've had the same results optimizing y=(x-n)^2 or other functions with clearly known minima over the search domain.